# Define Apex controller in javascript home component

Tags: javascript, controller, salesforce, apex

I have created a custom object `Code_Postal__c`.
The goal is to check into my `Code_Postal__c` record the city's name with the same ZipCode set by the user on an Account record page.

I don't need, and don't want to create a custom visualforce page.

The fun fact is that my field is pre-populate with the good values but the research doesn't work.
When I inspected my page to check why my autocomplete doesn't work I got the error below:

```
**Uncaught ReferenceError: AutoCompleteController is not defined e?retURL=%2F001M000000UyrUl:24
j$.autocomplete.source e?retURL=%2F001M000000UyrUl:24
$.widget._search jquery-ui.js:6563
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js:413
$.widget.search jquery-ui.js:6555
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js:413
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js:6536
handlerProxy**
```

Here my controller:

```
global with sharing class AutoCompleteController {
//private final Movie__c mov; 
private Code_Postal__c cpCheck;
private Account accToCheck;

    // Instance fields
    public String searchTerm {get; set;}
    public String selectedMovie {get; set;}

    // Constructor
    public AutoCompleteController() {

    }
    public AutoCompleteController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.accToCheck = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
    //this.mov= (Movie__c)stdController.getRecord();
}

// JS Remoting action called when searching for a cp
@RemoteAction
global static List<Code_Postal__c> searchMovie(String searchTerm) {
    System.debug('Movie Name is: '+searchTerm );
    List<Code_Postal__c> movies = Database.query('Select Commune__c, Code_Postal__c from Code_Postal__c where Code_Postal__c like \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchTerm) + '%\'');
    return movies;
}
```

}

Here my component :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*Create a new variable j$ just to avoid any conflicts with other libraries which may be using $.*/
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    /*Capture the list of countries in a Array.*/

    /*on Document ready*/
    j$(document).ready(function(){
        var PLACEHOLDER = 'Enter Code_Postal__c Here'; 
        var movieObjects;
        var queryTerm;

        j$('[id$=acc18zip]').autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function(request, response) {
                        queryTerm = request.term;

                           AutoCompleteController.searchMovie(request.term, function(result, event){
                            if(event.type == 'exception') {
                                  alert(event.message);
                            } else {
                                 movieObjects = result;
                                 response(movieObjects);
                            }
                        });
                   },
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    j$('[id$=acc18zip]').val( ui.item.Code_Postal__c );
                    j$('[id$=acc18city]').val( ui.item.Commune__c );
                    return false;
                    },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                        j$('[id$=acc18zip]').val( ui.item.Code_Postal__c );
                        return false;
                    },
         })

         .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            var entry = "<a>" + item.Code_Postal__c + " " +item.Commune__c;

            entry = entry + "</a>";
            entry = entry.replace(queryTerm, "<b>" + queryTerm + "</b>");
            return j$( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( entry )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };

        /* Add or remove placeholder values*/
        j$('[id$=acc18zip]').val(PLACEHOLDER);
        j$('[id$=acc18zip]').on("focus",  function(event){
            j$tgt = j$(event.target);
            if(j$tgt.val() === PLACEHOLDER ){
                j$tgt.val('');
                j$tgt.removeClass('placeHolder');
            }
        });
        j$('[id$=acc18zip]').on( "blur",  function(event){
            j$tgt = j$(event.target);
            if(j$tgt.val() === '' ){
                j$tgt.val(PLACEHOLDER);
                j$tgt.addClass('placeHolder');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think you can access your apex controller if you have not affiliated it with your page using visualforce, even for remote javascript. I was under the belief that if you want to access SF without VF (even light), you should make an apex REST service which you can call with ajax from js. (not 100% sure of this, but this is how i've been doing it)

Comment: Thanks i got it! In this case i have to use the Ajax Tool kit to connect myself to Salesforce (get the ssid and make my request).

Comment: Maybe you can write that up with some code as an answer ? That may help others in the future and not keep this question open and unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said , i found a way to make my auto-complete.
It's making a request, and parsing my string.
It's not working with parameter..='( I'm trying to find a way to do it dynamically and parse my object (with the item?)
Anyway this example is working :

The controller :

```
global class cpSearch2{ 
    webService static String searchCP() {
        String pickValues='';
        for(Code_Postal__c cp : [Select Commune__c, Code_Postal__c from Code_Postal__c ]){
               pickValues = pickValues +cp.Code_Postal__c+ ' - ' + cp.Commune__c+'+';
        }
        return pickValues;
    }
}
```

My javascript component:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>var url = document.URL;
if(url.indexOf('001')!=-1)    
{                
    var sid = document.cookie.match(' sid=([^;]*)')[1];   
    sforce.debug.trace=true;
    sforce.connection.sessionId = sid;
    var stages = sforce.apex.execute("cpSearch2", "searchCP", {});
    var staheArray = stages.toString().split("+");
    $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = staheArray;
        $( "#acc18zip" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
            });
        $( "#acc18zip" ).on("autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ){
            selectedArray = ui.item.value.split(" - ");
            $("#acc18zip").val(selectedArray[0]);
            $("#acc18city").val(selectedArray[1]);
            return false;  
        });
    });
}
</script>
```