# Salesforce & Javascript / Ajax - Trying to use a parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, salesforce, ajaxcontroltoolkit

*Following this post  :*

[Define Apex controller in javascript home component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614206/define-apex-controller-in-javascript-home-component)

I tried to improved it, because the limit of Salesforce for an SOQL request is **50k records**.

The **Code_Postal__c** object can have more than 50k of records.

I saw that we can parse item in javascript (i'm pretty bad with this language).
The idea is to make a dynamic call of my controller when the user will start typing the postal code ( id of the field = #acc18zip ). But i got an error with my item list, so i came back to use my string but it didn't work.
When i tried to find the error with the chrome console or firebug i saw this error into my console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

and when i start typing a postal code:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

My updated controller is this one :

```
global class cpSearch2{ 
    webService static String searchCP() {
        String pickValues='';
        for(Code_Postal__c cp : [Select Commune__c, Code_Postal__c from Code_Postal__c ]){
               pickValues = pickValues +cp.Code_Postal__c+ ' - ' + cp.Commune__c+'+';
        }
        return pickValues;
    }

    webService static string searchCP2(string searchTerm) {
        String pickValues='';
        for(Code_Postal__c cp : [Select Commune__c, Code_Postal__c from Code_Postal__c where Code_Postal__c LIKE :searchTerm]){
                pickValues = pickValues +cp.Code_Postal__c+ ' - ' + cp.Commune__c+'+';
        }
        return pickValues;
    }

    /*
    Function with list of object
    webService static list<Code_Postal__c> searchCP2(string searchTerm) {
        list<Code_Postal__c> matchingCP = new list<Code_Postal__c>();
        for(Code_Postal__c cp : [Select Commune__c, Code_Postal__c from Code_Postal__c where Code_Postal__c LIKE :searchTerm]){
               matchingCP.add(cp);
        }
        return matchingCP;
    }*/
}
```

and the updated javascript is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var url = document.URL;
if(url.indexOf('001')!=-1)    
{        
        var sid = document.cookie.match(' sid=([^;]*)')[1];        
        sforce.debug.trace=true;        
        sforce.connection.sessionId = sid;        ;
        var stages;
        var cpObjects;
        var queryTerm;
        $ = jQuery.noConflict();       
        $(function()             
            {                             
                $( "#acc18zip" ).autocomplete({
                       source:function( request, response ) {
                        queryTerm = request.term;
                        stages = sforce.apex.execute("cpSearch2", "searchCP2", {queryTerm,function(result, event)});
                        if(event.type == 'exception') {
                            alert(event.message);
                        } else {
                            cpObjects = stages.toString().split("+");
                            response(cpObjects);
                        }                       
                       },
                        focus: function( event, ui ) {
                            $("#acc18zip").val(selectedArray[0]);
                            $("#acc18city").val(selectedArray[1]);
                            return false;
                        },
                       select: function( event, ui ) {
                       console.log(ui.item); 
                       selectedArray = ui.item.split(" - ");
                       $("#acc18zip").val(selectedArray[0]);
                       $("#acc18city").val(selectedArray[1]);
                       return false;
                        }
                });     
            });    
}
</script>
```

Trying to follow this :

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp